# show div based on selected $index from list angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my HTML code

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-group text-left">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-click="showData($index)" ng-repeat="field in Data">
         {{ field.name }}</a>
    </ul>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div ng-repeat="field in Data" >
        <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="scenario in field.scenarios track by $index">
            <div class="panel-heading ">
                {{ scenario.name }}
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group p-body">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="values in scenarios.values track by $index">{{ value }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to show the `col-md-8` div data based on index selected from the `field.name` from `col-md-4` list group.

Here is my Sample Data

```
{
    "scenarios": [{
        "values": ["value 1",
        "value 2",
        "value 3"],
        "title": "some title"
    },
    {
        "values": ["value 1",
        "value 2",
        "value 3"],
        "title": "some title"
    },
    {
        "values": ["value 1",
        "value 2",
        "value 3"],
        "title": "some title"
    }],
    "description": "",
    "name": "Some name  "
}
```

The name is displayed on the left (in col-md-4)and the corresponding data has to be shown on the right(in col-md-8).
But I can't figure out how to do it. Any help ?

Comment: where is your `showData($index)` function

Comment: that is just the name I have given. what should I write in that function to display the data based on $index value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a scope varible to store selected index, depend on selected index show other div,

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-group text-left">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-click="selectedIndex = $index" ng-repeat="field in Data">
         {{ field.name }}</a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div ng-show="selectedIndex == $index" ng-repeat="field in Data">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="scenario in field.scenarios track by $index">
      <div class="panel-heading ">
        {{ scenario.name }}
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group p-body">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="values in scenarios.values track by $index">{{ value }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's pretty much overhead when you do an ng-repeat, while you only want to always display 1

Answer (score 1):

If you only are going to display one field object, I would just do the following:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-group text-left">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" 
           ng-click="selectedField = field" 
           ng-repeat="field in Data">
         {{ field.name }}</a>
    </ul>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- only if one is selected -->
    <div ng-if="selectedField">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" 
             <!-- get data from 'selectedField' -->
             ng-repeat="scenario in selectedField.scenarios track by $index">
            <!-- other stuff -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```